# Placing squares on a Cartesian plane and working out their X,Y coords based on sequence number

Tags: math, sequence, discrete-mathematics, cartesian

A bunch of guys and myself from work were trying to wrap our heads around this problem, but couldn't find a clean and efficient mathematical way to solve this problem. Here it is:

Given a standard Cartesian plane and a sequence of images (all square and of the same dimensions, we'll just say 1 unit for example) how do we organize them in such a fashion that they spiral around the origin (0,0) of the plane by their top left corner. But also more specifically, if given the number 25 for example (the 25th square in the sequence) what would it's X,Y coordinates be?

[image]

Hopefully this crude image helps explain the sequence. The very first square to be placed on the grid would be the red, then blue, yellow, purple, green, black, brown, and then so forth around as the dots illustrate.

We were hoping if there was a "relatively" simple mathematical formula for this, but maybe that's wishful thinking.

Comment: You should list the ordering. I assume all the squares are the first spiral around the origin and the dots are the second?

Comment: What do you mean by the coordinates? Center of square? Left corner?  For example -- what number would you assign to the black square? (2,-2)?

Comment: @r3oath Two comments: 1) You should label this question with the programming language in which you plan to implement your solution, and 2) you should review the well thought out answers given below.

Comment: The coordinates for the squares are respective to their top-left corner, so in the example image the black square would be at (1,-1). As for the programming language, any language solution would suffice assuming the answers don't make use of a library exclusive to that language. It's easy enough to translate over to other languages. But to be specific, this would be implemented in PHP.

Comment: I'll review all the given answers tomorrow morning at work with the other guys and then mark the best solution, they all look great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(On edit: I added a second function which enables the Cartesian coordinate version to be obtained directly.)

I got this far before my head exploded. It is closed form in the sense that it gives the coordinates of say the one millionth square without needing to place them one by one in a loop. Writing it down wouldn't give a nice formula but you could write as a piecewise defined formula with 8 pieces. The answer is given in 1-based grid-coordinates. The first coordinate tells you how many squares you are to the right or left of the y-axis and the second coordinate how far up or down. From these numbers it is relatively easy to e.g. get Cartesian coordinates of their top left corner. I implemented it in Python:

```
from math import sqrt, ceil

def coordinates(m):
    n = ceil(sqrt(m)/2) #shell number
    i = m - 4*(n-1)**2 #index in shell
    if i <= n:
        return (n,-i)
    elif i <= 2*n-1:
        return (2*n - i, -n)
    elif i <= 3*n - 1:
        return (2*n - 1 - i, -n)
    elif i <= 4*n - 2:
        return (-n, -4*n + 1  + i)
    elif i <= 5*n - 2:
        return (-n, -4*n + 2 + i)
    elif i <= 6*n - 3:
        return (-6*n + 2 + i, n)
    elif i <= 7*n - 3:
        return (-6*n + 3 + i,n)
    else:
        return (n, 8*n -3 - i)
```

To get the (x,y) Cartesian coordinates of the top left corners from the (i,j) grid coordinates you can use the following function, which has an optional width parameter to allow for non-unit squares:

```
def cartesianFromGrid(i,j,w = 1):
    x = w * (i if i < 0 else i - 1)
    y = w * (j if j > 0 else j + 1)
    return (x,y)
```

It is possible to directly get the Cartesian coordinates of the top left corner directly without first going through grid coordinates. The resulting formula involves fewer cases (since I don't need to skip from 1 directly to -1 or vice versa) though I am keeping both formulas in the answer since in many ways the grid perspective is more natural:

```
def  cartCoordinates(m):
    n = ceil(sqrt(m)/2) #shell number
    i = m - 4*(n-1)**2 #index in shell
    if i <= n:
        return (n-1,-i+1)
    elif i <= 3*n - 1:
        return (2*n - 1 - i, -n + 1)
    elif i <= (5*n - 2):
        return (-n, -4*n + 2 + i)
    elif i <= 7*n - 3:
        return (-6*n + 2 + i, n)
    else:
        return (n-1, 8 * n - 3 - i)
```

Output for 1-16:

```
>>> for n in range(1,17):
    print(n, ': grid coords =', coordinates(n),
          'Cartesian =',cartesianFromGrid(*coordinates(n)))


1 : grid coords = (1, -1) Cartesian = (0, 0)
2 : grid coords = (-1, -1) Cartesian = (-1, 0)
3 : grid coords = (-1, 1) Cartesian = (-1, 1)
4 : grid coords = (1, 1) Cartesian = (0, 1)
5 : grid coords = (2, -1) Cartesian = (1, 0)
6 : grid coords = (2, -2) Cartesian = (1, -1)
7 : grid coords = (1, -2) Cartesian = (0, -1)
8 : grid coords = (-1, -2) Cartesian = (-1, -1)
9 : grid coords = (-2, -2) Cartesian = (-2, -1)
10 : grid coords = (-2, -1) Cartesian = (-2, 0)
11 : grid coords = (-2, 1) Cartesian = (-2, 1)
12 : grid coords = (-2, 2) Cartesian = (-2, 2)
13 : grid coords = (-1, 2) Cartesian = (-1, 2)
14 : grid coords = (1, 2) Cartesian = (0, 2)
15 : grid coords = (2, 2) Cartesian = (1, 2)
16 : grid coords = (2, 1) Cartesian = (1, 1)
```

In case you wondered:

```
>>> coordinates(1000000)
(500, 1)
```

This last answer makes sense since the one millionth square is the capstone of a 1000x1000 grid of squares.

I used the above to place colored squares on a tkinter canvas widget:

[image]

Comment: All of the answers were well thought out and constructive, but yours was the most elegant and solved the problem we had, with the least amount of code, great job!

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer (now relegated to the revision history) was a recursive solution. Below is what I would call a "cyclic" solution.

The idea is that we make multiple revolutions around a square. At any given index:

- We are making a revolution around the outside of a smaller square
- We are on one side of this square
- We are partially down one side of this square

By keeping track of the square, the side, and the distance down the side, we can index every point.

We go around a square by drawing 4 equal lines. (Call them "segments".) We start each revolution in the middle of the first segment.

For example:

Revolution 1 is around a square of size 0, segments of length 1:

```
            O    OO
 O    OO    OO   OO
```

Revolution 2 is around a square of size 4, segments of length 3:

```
            O     OOOO  OOOO 
 OO    OO   OOO   OOO   OOOO
 OOO   OOO  OOOO  OOOO  OOOO
   O  OOOO  OOOO  OOOO  OOOO
```

Revolution 3 is around a square of size 16, segments of length 5:

```
                 O       OOOOOO  OOOOOO
 OOOO    OOOO    OOOOO   OOOOO   OOOOOO
 OOOO    OOOO    OOOOO   OOOOO   OOOOOO
 OOOOO   OOOOO   OOOOOO  OOOOOO  OOOOOO
 OOOOO   OOOOO   OOOOOO  OOOOOO  OOOOOO
     O  OOOOOO   OOOOOO  OOOOOO  OOOOOO
```

Below is an implementation in Python.

```
import math

def makeSquare(main_index, offset_size):
    step_index = int(math.sqrt(main_index))/2   # How many revolutions have we made?
    last_square = int(math.pow(step_index*2,2)) # Whats the largest square less than main_index?
    segment_length = (2 * step_index) + 1       # How long is the side of the square we've made so far? The segment length is 1 more than that.

    main_index = main_index + step_index + 1    # Skip ahead so we start in the middle of the right side instead of the top. We do some modulo stuff below to wrap around.

    segment_index = (main_index - last_square) / segment_length # Which segment are we on?
    dot_index = main_index - segment_index*segment_length - last_square # How far along the segment are we?

    draw_functions = [
        lambda i, size:  [size,     size - i], # Draw the right side of a square
        lambda i, size:  [size - i, 0       ], # Draw the bottom of a square
        lambda i, size:  [0,        i       ], # Draw the left side of a square
        lambda i, size:  [i,        size    ], # Draw the top of a square
    ]    

    x, y = draw_functions[segment_index % 4](dot_index % (4 * segment_length), segment_length)
    return [ x + offset_size - step_index - 1, y + offset_size - step_index - 1]

# Print the points to the console in sequence
import time, os
step = 4
points = [makeSquare(i, step) for i in range(int(math.pow(step*2,2)))]
board = [[" " for x in range(step*2)] for x in range(step*2)] 
for p in range(len(points)):
    print
    print p, "------------------"
    board[step*2-1 - points[p][1]][points[p][0]] = "O" # Do some coordinate wrangling so we have normal X and Y
    print (os.linesep).join([''.join(row) for row in board])
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using 1 based indexing you can use the following algorithm to find your answer (not sure if a closed form solution exists).

The idea behind this is to find which layer you're in (how far is your x or y away from 0). Then find which quadrant you're in. Then figure out which side you're in then figure out the coordinates.

```
get_coords(n)
    layer = 1
    while (n > 3 * layer * layer + (layer+1)*(layer+1))
        ++layer
    layer_ind = n - 3 * (layer - 1) * (layer - 1) - layer * layer
    if (layer_ind < 2 * layer + 1) # in bottom right
        if (layer_ind <= layer + 1)
            return (layer, - layer_ind + 1)
        else
            return (2 * layer + 1 - layer_ind, -layer)
    else if ((layer_ind - 2 * layer - 1)/(2 * layer - 1) < 1) # bottom left
        layer_ind = layer_ind - 2 * layer - 1
        if (layer_ind <= layer)
            return (-layer_ind+1, -layer+1)
        else
            return (-layer+1, -2*layer + 1 + layer_ind)
    else if ((layer_ind - 2 * layer - 1)/(2 * layer - 1) < 2) # top left
        layer_ind = layer_ind - 4 * layer
        if (layer_ind <= layer)
            return (-layer+1, layer_ind)
        else
            return (layer_ind - 2 * layer, layer)
    else # top right
        layer_ind = layer_ind - 6 * layer + 1
        if (layer_ind <= layer)
            return (layer_ind-1, layer)
        else
            return (layer-1, 2 * layer - layer_ind)
```